# Doing filter by select value is not working

Tags: angularjs

Not able to add the selected value to the filter in angularjs im getting this error(Error: Unexpected token .)

Inside controller

```
$scope.search_type_options=[{name:"Name",value:"name"},{name:"Id",value:"id"},{name:"Update By",value:"updated_by"}];

$scope.search_val = function()
{
   $scope.fs={$scope.search_type.value:$scope.search_txt};
   $scope.filter_dt=$filter('filter')($scope.temp_data,$scope.fs);
}
```

I need output like
    {name:"raj"}

Inside Template

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select name="search_type"  ng-model="search_type" ng-options="item as item.name for item in search_type_options">
  <option value="">--select search type</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search_txt" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
</div>
  <button type="submit" ng-model="search_btn" ng-click="search_val()"class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: at which line ?and please share $scope.temp_data data also

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is a correct js syntax

`$scope.fs={$scope.search_type.value:$scope.search_txt};`

normally it should be written like this

```
$scope.fs = {};
$scope.fs[$scope.search_type.value] = $scope.search_txt;
```